# Images that is rendered on top of each other in list

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am creating an element based on a Monotouch element. What happens with this is that is creates a list (like the Twitter Timeline) with a subject, domainname and Fav-Icon in each cell. And THE PROBLEM is this:
the first and last fav-icon of the list is shown twice, hence they are on top of each other.

Below is the code. Can anyone see what mistake I have made? /Robert

```
public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
{
    const int padright = 12;//21;
    var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
    bool highlighted = (Superview.Superview as UITableViewCell).Highlighted;

                var bounds = Bounds;
                var midx = bounds.Width/2;
                if (highlighted){
                    UIColor.FromRGB (4, 0x79, 0xef).SetColor ();
                    ctx.FillRect (bounds);
                    //Images.MenuShadow.Draw (bounds, CGBlendMode.Normal, 0.5f);
                    //textColor = UIColor.White;
                } else {
                    UIColor.White.SetColor ();
                    ctx.FillRect (bounds);
                    ctx.DrawLinearGradient (bottomGradient, new PointF (midx, bounds.Height-17), new PointF (midx, bounds.Height), 0);
                    ctx.DrawLinearGradient (topGradient, new PointF (midx, 1), new PointF (midx, 3), 0);
                }

        float boxWidth;
        float boxHeight = Bounds.Height;
        boxWidth = 0;
        //SizeF ssize;
        //string label;
        //label = Date;
        //ssize = StringSize (label, SubjectFont);
        //float dateSize = ssize.Width + padright + 5;
        //DrawString (label, new RectangleF (Bounds.Width-dateSize-5, 5, dateSize, 14), DateFont, UILineBreakMode.Clip, UITextAlignment.Right);

        const int offset = 46; //33;
        float bw = Bounds.Width-offset;
        UIColor.Black.SetColor ();

        //Extracting the domain name that I get.
        string domainName = new Uri(Sender).DnsSafeHost;
        if(domainName.StartsWith("www"))
        {
            domainName = domainName.Substring(4, domainName.Length-4);
        }

        //Checking to see if there is any subdomain.
        //If so, I start at the first dot to get the domainname "clean".
        int countDots = domainName.Split('.').Length - 1;
        if(countDots > 1)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Dots: " + countDots);
        int i = domainName.IndexOf('.') + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Position: " + i);
            domainName = domainName.Substring(i).Trim();
            Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + domainName);
        }

        DrawString (Subject, new RectangleF (offset, 6, bw-boxWidth-5, 24), SubjectFont, UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation, UITextAlignment.Left);
        DrawString (domainName, new PointF (offset, 28), bw/*-dateSize*/, SenderFont, UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation);

        //Getting the fav icon from the domainname and posting it to g.etfv.co.
        string favUrl = "http://www."+domainName;
        Console.WriteLine("Fav icon: " + favUrl);
        Uri imageBackground = null;
        imageBackground = new Uri ("http://g.etfv.co/"+ favUrl);
        var avatar = ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage (imageBackground, this);
        var imageRect = new RectangleF(15f, 10f, 16f, 16f); 
        using (var myImage = new UIImageView(imageRect))
        {
            if(avatar == null)
            {
                //A local avatar if something goes wrong
                string localAvatar = "Images/avatar.png";
                myImage.Image = UIImage.FromFile(localAvatar);
            }
            else
            {myImage.Image = avatar;}
            AddSubview(myImage);
        }
        avatar = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone see what mistake I have made?

#### Part 1...

Your description 'hence they are on top of each other' isn't entirely clear.

But I'm guessing that the problem might be hidden behind what this method does?

```
        var avatar = ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage (imageBackground, this);
```

If this requests the avatar asynchronously, then you need to be sure that when the asynchronous method returns that the cell hasn't been reused for a different location.

In TweetStation this is done in these lines in the `void IImageUpdated.UpdatedImage (long onId)` callback:

```
    // Discard notifications that might have been queued for an old cell
    if (tweet == null || (tweet.UserId != onId && tweet.RetweeterId != onId))
        return;
```

Do you have similar lines in your callback?

---

> Can anyone see what mistake I have made?

#### Part 2...

I would say you've made the mistake of making one method so long that even you can't read it.

Consider using [refactoring tools](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Feature_List/Refactoring) like 'Extract Method' in order to break it down into smaller functions which make sense. See

This is all part of normal refactoring - write code in one function then refactor it into smaller parts as it becomes too long and unwieldy...

... and many people would say the methods I write are too small ...

... so whatever you do just find something that works for you and your code :)

Comment: Hey, I have this code:   public void UpdatedImage (Uri imageBackground)
  {
   ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage(imageBackground, this);
  }